# Serializing form inputs with jquery

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a form with many hidden divs and a select for showing a single div.

But when submitting the data to the server, all data is sended and some values are lost (fields with the same name in different divs).

This is a scenario example:

```
<form>
  <select>
    <option value="ga">GA</option>
    <option value="om">OM</option>
  </select>

  <div class="ga">
   <input type="text" name="a_field" />
   <input type="text" name="a_field_2" />
   ...code
  </div>

  <div class="om">
   <input type="text" name="a_field_2" />
   <input type="text" name="a_field_100" />
   ...code
  </div>

</form>
```

How can I do for only serialize the div I want?

My first approach was remove the hidden divs in the beforeSerialize method from ajaxForm, but now I need to serialize the values when clicking another links to make another calls (and not to submitting the form).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are your fields the same name? jQuery is just dumping a key-value pair in an object and passing _that_ object as parameters. Try renaming your fields, or working on making elements with the same name in to an array instead. (facsimile of `<input name="foo[]" /><input name="foo[]" />`

Comment: I've solved it detaching the divs, saving it in an array, and renderizing when needed. But thanks, Brad and MaXo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it manually:

```
var serial = new Array();
var i = 0;
$('.om input').each( function(){
    serial[i++] = $(this).attr('name')[0]+'='+$(this).html()[0];
});
serial.join('&');
```

Comment: Your solution will tack on an extra `&` at the end. I've corrected.